# Web service request ignores basic WSDL XML element restrictions

Tags: java, web-services, jboss5.x

I have encountered some difficulties while trying to validate an incoming soap message to a service I have running on JBoss AS (v. 5.1.0).

In my code, I have explicitly set some fields to be required, eg:

```
public class MyClass {
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false)
    private List<myOtherObjects> myList;
}
```

This requirement is also reflected in the WSDL (note the lack of minOccurs="0"):

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="myList" type="tns:myOtherObjects" />
```

However, when I do a test soap message that has myList set to empty or null, these restrictions are completely ignored, forcing me to validate manually within the application logic on the service.

I did some searching on the Internet and found out that, on WebLogic, the validation does not seem to be enabled by default, though it can be turned on by modifying the weblogic-webservices.xml file. (http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=783972&tstart=115)

I’m wondering if there is something similar that I have to do with JBoss AS to enable automatic validation before the soap message reaches the service. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oliver

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `required` and `nillable` aren't used by the validation routines. You need to tell JBoss WebServices to validate against the schema, which it won't do by default. I don't know how to do this, though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I searched around more and it seemed that I could use @SchemaValidation to accomplish what I wanted to do, but I'm still in the process of figuring how it would work...If anyone can give me some pointers in this area would be great.

Comment: Ok. I got the validation working by adding the annotation @SchemaValidation (enabled = true) to the service class. It looks something like this: 

@WebService
@SchemaValidation (enabled=true) 
public class MyServices {
    @WebMethod(action="echoAction") 
    public String echo(@WebParam(name="word") String word)throws
    Exception{

Answer (score 0):

On your porttype:

```
@SchemaValidation(handler = YourSchemaValidationErrorHandler.class)
@WebService
@Stateless
public class ......... {

}
```